# How do I retrieve the comment and image for a like generated by a like button on a webpage using FQL?

Tags: facebook-fql

Information about a URL is available from the link_stats table which gives a count of the number of likes, shares, comments etc.

That said I can't find a way to retrieve the data from a specific instance of a like button press as it appears in the users activity feed e.g. Sarah Thomson likes a link   . Is this data available using FQL? Ideally I would like to be able to find and list all friends of the user who have liked a link from a site along with that links details (comment, image, etc).

Any guidance is much appreciated.

****EDIT****

So I have tried a few of the tables

```
select object_id, post_id, object_type from like where user_id=me()
```

this gets a list of likes that includes those generated by the url but cannot be index against a user that is not the current session user

The closest i have found is a called to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes
```

however this requires a call for each user and then a further call for each like to get the image, url info.

Annoyingly none of this information shows up in the regular /me/feed call despite it being visible in the users timeline.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code you already have?

Comment: Update to include some of the endpoints i have tried.